# How can I change style of algrenewcommand?

Tags: auctex, comments

When I use `\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill// #1}` it has following comment style:

[image]

Instead can I have following `//`, if you look closely end of line there is is half circle and its has more angle. Note that the image is taken from Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms book:

[image]

---

my latex code:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\textbf{//}\,#1}
\begin{document}
\phantom{} \\
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \If{$quality \geq 9$}
    \State $a \gets perfect$  \algorithmiccomment{\([\mathrm{A}]\)}
  \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The slashes are in Times and the math is in Computer Modern. Very bad setup of IEEEtran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should, first of all, avoid the IEEEtran default setting for `compsoc` of text in Palatino and math in Computer Modern.

Next, multiletter variables should not be just math mode, but either `\mathrm` or `\mathit` (otherwise the interletter spacing would be funny and wrong). Using a command makes it possible to change preferences by acting on the definition, rather than chasing the whole document.

Finally, the slashes in Palatino have sharp ends. The picture you show possibly uses Computer Modern Typewriter for the slashes.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\cslashes\ #1}

\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\qquad\cslashes\ #1}

\newcommand{\cslashes}{{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont/\!/}}
\newcommand{\tvar}[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \If{$\tvar{quality} \geq 9$}
    \State $a \gets \tvar{perfect}$  \algorithmiccomment{forest}
  \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Note that the second redefinition of `\algorithmiccomment` is just to get a smaller picture, remove it in your code.

[image]

Here's the output with the default (and disputable) IEEEtran style obtained by removing the call to NewPX.

[image]

And here the output if you also don't follow the advice of formatting the multiletter variables.

[image]

The code in `IEEEtran` that announces Palatino:

```
% V1.7 compsoc nonconference papers, use Palatino/Palladio as the main text font,
% not Times Roman.
\@IEEEcompsocnotconfonly{\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}}
```

If you replace

```
\newcommand{\cslashes}{{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont/\!/}}
```

with

```
\newcommand{\cslashes}{{\fontfamily{lmtt}\fontseries{b}\selectfont/\!/}}
```

you get

[image]

Comment: In the Cormen' books `//` was bold, to make it bold what should I do? I have tried to add `\fontseries{ub}` in the `\cslashes` definition but it did not help :(

Comment: You get bolder slashes with `\fontfamily{lmtt}\fontseries{b}` instead of `\fontfamily{cmtt}`.

Comment: To see the affect I have tried with ultra-bold option as: `\newcommand{\cslashes}{{\fontfamily{lmtt}\fontseries{ub}\selectfont/\!/}}` , but the boldness weight is not affected , is it normal?

Comment: @alper There is no ultrabold for `lmtt`.

Comment: I was looking for `extra bold`. As I understand I can get bold `{b}` at most, but not `Extra Bold      eb` or `ub`

Comment: @alper Find a font with the desired weight and sporting round end slashes. Very few, if any, exist. Surely neither Computer Modern nor Latin Modern have extra bold weight.

Comment: I had no idea `lmtt` font family existed and its under math in Computer Modern. Thanks again for the detailed answer and comments